# securityadmin role Can create a database

Tags: sql-server-2008, database-administration

I am having `securityadmin` role in **mssql 2008**.

As per the Doc  The `securityadmin` role should be treated as `equivalent` to the sysadmin role Can **create a database** ?

what is the **difference** between `securityadmin` role and `sysadmin` role

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**sysadmin**

```
Members of the sysadmin fixed server role can perform any activity in the server.
```

**securityadmin**

```
Members of the securityadmin fixed server role manage logins and their properties.
They can GRANT, DENY, and REVOKE server-level permissions.
They can also GRANT, DENY, and REVOKE database-level permissions 
if they have access to a database.
Additionally, they can reset passwords for SQL Server logins.
```

**Final Note:**

```
The ability to grant access to the Database Engine and to configure 
user permissions allows the security admin to assign most server permissions.
The securityadmin role should be treated as equivalent to the sysadmin role.
```

**[For any Queries Refer the Source](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-IN/library/ms188659.aspx)**

Comment: i am having security admin permission and i am not able to give give the security admin permission to another user " User does not have permission this action MS Error : 15247 " is it possible to edited the security admin role/ how it is possible ?

Comment: `EXEC sp_addsrvrolemember 'username', 'securityadmin'` ? Is that what you did?

Comment: its working .. able to add by executing above query.. but its not working in management studio .. Then i can give sysadmin privilege too? .. thanks 4 u r help

Answer (score 0):

FYI..

if we talk scope wise

sysadmin role has larger scope i.e server level and database level and is super user in all db's of server and can perform any server/admin/db activity.

Security admin role is also a server role but slighly less scoped and lacking some of the priviledges compared to sysadmin.

it have specifically used many times for grant ,deny ,revoke server and db permission for role ,objects and can be used for execute as clause too..